# Copy specific cell contents into clipboard in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am a frequent user of Excel. Now I was looking to copy some of specific cells into clipboard for pasting them in another application.

I could see the copy single cell data into clipboard. Can someone suggest steps to make a configurable way to copy specific cell data into clipboard by the click of a button?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any sheet in the workbook and clear the clipboard before copying. Right click the Excel logo just to the left of File on the menu bar, select View Code and paste in

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Target.Copy
End Sub
```

then press ALT + Q to return to your sheet.

Comment: i managed to get the view code. But when i look into it there is already code in it. like this 'Private Sub btnGenTestSumm_Click()

End Sub
'

Comment: ok. did the same. but then how shall it works. I mean, I would like to select the cells and then click on this ? please treat me as a beginer

Comment: Yes! Just select the cells you want to copy, you would see that they are highlighted, just like when you use Ctrl + C !!

Comment: Yes.. but when i opened the clipboard, the cell contents are not in it. Also, when i press CTRL+V also , the contents are not pasting..

Comment: Not sure if you are doing it right then, are the cells highlighted when you click on them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68319/discussion-between-neomen-and-master-mind).

Comment: Yes, it gets highlighted Chat is blocked in my network.

Comment: with dotted flickering lines?

Comment: no, when i select the cells, a light blue shade is seen. I think its is the general highlight of Excel. sorry my mistake

Comment: this is what i can see in my VB.....  'Private Sub btnGenTestSumm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Target.Copy
End Sub
'

Comment: Not sure if the already existing function is interferring, you might want to try the code in the fresh excel sheet or you could comment out the already existing code.

Comment: In a new sheet , **1**) i tried with a button and on its right click i removed all the defaults and pasted the above code. **2**) then i selected the cells-- which are not seen with that dotted flickering lines **3**) And still i cant see the contents in the clipboard.... :(

Comment: I am really not sure what is the mistake that you are making! At most i could post screenshots of how I have done it

Comment: shall i show my code again- or shall i post it in a jsfiddle for u to easily see

Comment: I am not able to upload pics right now. May be I will do it later. Meanwhile try going through this site - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/418891-copy-cell-clipboard-single-click.html